# get jqueryui background button color via class

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Good morning:
I have some forms and want to use the background color of the ui active theme. I found a lot of cases to replace the property background, but none to GET the background color.

I want to put something like :

```
<div class='ui-button-background---or-whatever-it-is' ...>
    <span class='ui-button-color----or-whatever-it-is' ...>
        Sample title with color & background colors of the jqueryui button
    </span>
</div>
```

and the set the div background with the button background color

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which jqueryui class(es) do i have to set in my div to use the button background color? maybe my english is not good, by looking the sample you can have an idea of what i need

Comment: where is your buttton ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you're asking, but I think this might be what you're looking for.

Try this to **Get** the background color:

```
$('.ui-button-background').css('background-color');
```

**Setting** a background-color (or any other css property) you only add the 2nd argument:

```
$('.ui-button-background').css('background-color', 'red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9sx1duj/)

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I need to get the theme jqyeryui background, not my background. I mean, in

Comment: @GrenvilleTryon, I see. If you are using Chrome or Firefox right-click the button and select "Inspect Element". Then on right-hand side you'll see a "Styles" tab which shows all styles for that element from all CSS. Look for a `background` property in there from a file called `jquery-ui.css`. Then, use my code to select that css class.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try it.

Comment: Eureka! That was the buggy one: "ui-widget ui-state-default" (a collection of  two classes gives me the needed theme background). You not only give me the answer, but give me a way to use a tool in advance. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9sx1duj/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='ui-button-background div1'>
    <span class='ui-button-color div2'>
        Sample title with color & background colors of the jqueryui button
    <input class="button" type="button" style="background-color:red;"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var backgrnd = $(".button").css("background-color");

$(".div1").css("background-color",backgrnd );

$(".div2").css("background-color",backgrnd );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´d tried your sample (i removed your style css because i need the theme background color) but my div didnt get the background color of the button.

Comment: can you paste the html here

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="scripts/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <div class='ui-button-background div1'>
 <span class='ui-button-color div2'>
        Sample title with color & background colors of the jqueryui button
    <button class='button'>aaa</button>
    </span>
</div> That´s ALL the code.

Comment: did you assign a color to your button ?

Comment: Sorry, cant find a way to format properly. As you can see, I just put the css and want to use the background button color via css.

Comment: No.  I need to use the jqueryui theme colors, no my colors.

Comment: your button dont have color ,,,, thats why you did not get any color

Comment: I downloaded from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ the sunny theme. The button has a background color, somewhere in the css (JIC im properly referencing the css filename).

Comment: change  this  line and check  `var backgrnd = $("button").css("background-color");`